# Passing value of pointer with func golang

Tags: pointers, go

how i can pass value of c without return and print it at func main

```
func main() {
    a := 10
    b := 5
    jumlah(&a, &b)
}
func jumlah(angka1 *int, angka2 *int) {
    c := *angka1 * *angka2
}
```

Comment: Also pass the address of c like `jumlah(&a, &b, &c)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the address of `c` so that update the data in the function.

```
func main() {
    a := 10
    b := 5
    var c int
    jumlah(&a, &b,&c)
    fmt.Print(c)

}
func jumlah(angka1 *int, angka2 *int, c *int){
    *c = *angka1 * *angka2
}
```

Try to explore [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1)

Comment: this i'm looking for, thx

Comment: @newbie1123 https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This is you how you can do it. But I also suggest please do the [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) so that you can have an idea of Go.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        var a, b, c int = 10, 5, 0
        jumlah(&a, &b, &c)
        fmt.Println("Result: ", c)
}

func jumlah(angka1 *int, angka2 *int, c *int) {
        *c = *angka1 * *angka2
}
```